# Is creating a backdoor without specifying an IP possible?

Tags: ip, backdoor

Is it possible to create a backdoor without configuring an IP? For example, if I want to create a listener that everyone can access, what can I do? Something like a backdoor, RAT or something like that?

Comment: I don't understand the question. "backdoor" is a very broad term, but generally means opening a listening port that nobody else is likely to find, or opening a reverse shell back to your server, or weakening the crypto in some way that you will be able to decrypt it but it will not be obvious to others, etc.

It usually doesn't have anything to do with the IP of the victim machine.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth this is why metasploit shaped me...set lhost and lport. I want know if is possible create a backdoor(?) without set the lhost, so two pc with different ip know the public ip of the victim can execute such exploit because they know that at port 44444 there is a service in listening.

Comment: I think you are asking about a "netcat listener"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only used to seeing Meterpreter, but any service with a listening port could work. What the service allows you to do depends on what that service does.

The first such service that was used for malicious purposes (which Meterpreter is based on) is called `netcat`, also know as `nc`. You set up a netcat listener.

```
nc -l 44444
```